# Getting started with Mac development

Tags: cocoa, macos

How long does it take for an experienced Windows programmer to learn writing simple software for Mac OS X?

Where does one start and what tools will be necessary?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[THIS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619).  I came from a Win32 API background programming lately a lot in C# and I was able to pick up on Objective-C and Cocoa very quickly by working through the book.  You will be pleasantly surprised, the APIs are very rich and just wonderful.  Reflection is a first class citizen which makes things very easy.

Xcode is of course free and available on your Mac OS X installation disk.

Edit: it took me about 2 weeks to come up to speed and write simple applications.  I think this is because the language and API are easy to learn and use and [Aaron Hillegass](http://www.bignerdranch.com/instructors/hillegass.shtml)'s [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619) was a big help.

Comment: New edition available: http://www.amazon.com/Cocoa-Programming-Mac-4th-Edition/dp/0321774086/ref=dp_ob_title_bk

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162099/best-way-to-get-started-with-mac-development) for info - pretty much a duplicate question to this one.  Definitely just go with Xcode and I think you'll find the Mac community pretty helpful - I have, at least.

Answer (score 3):

Start by checking out the [Apple Developer Connection](http://developer.apple.com/). There's a lot of documentation there. OS X comes with all the development tools you need to get started, just install XCode from the OSX CD.

Answer (score 2):

I would start here:

http://www.cocoadevcentral.com/

It's a great site with good resources on learning obj-c and cocoa.

This is also a great book:

http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003012/?CMP=AFC-ak_book&ATT=Learning+Cocoa+with+Objective-C

Comment: Yes, the samples on cocoadvcenral are great

Answer (score 2):

Well, first you get a hoodie and a smug sense of entitlement....

All kidding aside, the Aaron Hillegass book, a great idea, and the Apple doco are all you need to get started (oh yeah, and a Mac). I think the biggest barrier for me was figuring out Xcode since I come from a Visual Studio background.

How long it takes is a function of the level of your interest and your passion about your project.

The tools have come a long, long way since the days of Interface Builder in Mac OS X 10.0, that's for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the "how long" question would depend on what languages you are used to using.

In terms of reference material, I have heard good things about ["Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X"](http://www.compman.co.uk/scripts/browse.asp?ref=880360), and I'd love to have time to play with it for myself.  Unfortunately, the day job takes up enough of my time. :)

Answer (score 1):

CS193E (from stanford) is a nice course. Lots of material. Really understanding the use of class clusters, delegation, etc. takes some time, getting started does not.

Answer (score 1):

"Step into XCode" is a great intro to the development environment; since the book works through taking a simple command-line linear regression program all the way to a fairly sophisticated application (Core Data, Spotlight importers, etc.), you'll learn quite a lot by osmosis.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's the little things... On
   Windows, I liked the PowerToy called
   "Open Command Here" that allowed me
   to open a DOS CMD window from
   Explorer and automatically set the
   current directory. On the MAC, I got
   "On My Command" which allows you to
   create simple macros easily, and
   comes with a library of useful ones,
   like "Open Terminal Here", "New text
   File...", etc.
2. Install Eclipse. I loved using
       Eclipse on Windows, and it works
       great on the MAC, making me feel
       right at home. I even found that
       Eclipse has plugins for Perl and
       ActionScript.
3. Learn Unix (if you don't know it
       already). I had years of Unix
       experience prior to programming
       Windows, and it comes in handy.
       Knowing Perl helps a lot as well.
4. I started my new position last
   October, which was when I made the
   switch from Windows to MAC. By March
   I was fairly comfortable in my
   understanding of things. Then again,
   my development platform is AS2 and
   AS2 in Flash, which is
   cross-platform.

Comment: chernoch:can i able apple to develop app using Windows os which will support mac os ??????

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to try out the [Qt SDK](http://qt.nokia.com/), and write cross-platform applications that run on Windows, Mac and other platforms.

I started learning Qt when I joined Qt software, and it didn't take long for me to start writing simple software, even though I don't work as a developer.